Correct cable for Elmo TRV-16G output
I have an Elmo TRV-16G that I'm trying to connect to an Elgato video capture device. I'm trying to confirm that I'm purchasing the correct cable for the connection.



It appears to have two BNC connections for video and single RCA for audio. But, what's throwing me off is the gen-lock label? I've not run across that before. I'm looking to get a 2-BNC to single S-Video cable. Does that seem like the proper setup? I found a manual for the TRV-16 but it only shows a single RCA jack for video and another for audio, so it wasn't any help.

Here's the cable I'm considering


does yours also have an s-video output? If it does, this might work better. Genlock is a clocked output to provide video clock to any input device that uses it. In this example he uses the S-video out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0GPhV_XNrA

Thanks for replying. No, the only connections it has are the three shown. I'm thinking that the two BNC are the S-Video out, but trying to confirm before I spend money on an adapter.
